# Using HEX character on forms button, but one character isn`t displaying - others work fine

Tags: forms, powershell, user-interface, button, fonts

I'm trying to use a 'forward' arrow character on my form button ([char]0x84 from the WingDings 3 font), to match the 'back' arrow ([char]0x83), but for some reason the 'forward' arrow doesn't show on the button. I've tried other HEX values and they work fine. HEX values were sourced from MS Word. Below is my MRE showing correct "back" button, blank "forward" button, plus a spare.

I *could* just use different symbols, but curious to know if there is a reason for this one character not working.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Size = '800,600'

$buttFACE1 = [char]0x83 # Back arrow from WingDings3
$buttFACE2 = [char]0x84 # Forward arrow from WingDings3 <- NOT WORKING
$buttFACE3 = [char]0x86 # Spare button for testing

$navFONT = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("WingDings 3","14",[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)

#################################################
# NAV BACK BUTTON
$navBACK = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$navBACK.Location = '10,10'
$navBACK.Size = '30,30'
$navBack.Font = $navFONT
$navBACK.Text = $buttFACE1
$navBACK.Enabled = $True
$Form.Controls.Add($navBACK)

####################################################
# NAV FORWARD BUTTON
$navFORWARD = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$navFORWARD.Location = '50,10'
$navFORWARD.Size = '30,30'
$navFORWARD.Font = $navFONT
$navFORWARD.Text = $buttFACE2
$navFORWARD.Enabled = $True
$Form.Controls.Add($navFORWARD)

##################################################
# SPARE BUTTON
$navSPARE = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$navSPARE.Location = '90,10'
$navSPARE.Size = '30,30'
$navSPARE.Font = $navFONT
$navSPARE.Text = $buttFACE3
$navSPARE.Enabled = $True
$Form.Controls.Add($navSPARE)

$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this. This forum has been a massive help since my organisation decided HTA's were too risky (I know, right!).

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your form? I've tried here and I see a back and a forward icon, *but* they are in two different styles - one has a flat back and one is chevroned... https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Tulz.png. Also, lol at variable names - ```$buttface1``` :-)

Comment: Try characters `0x74` (triangleleft) and `0x75` (triangleright) or `0x7C` (triangle45left) and `0x7D` (triangle45right). See [here](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings-3.html)

Comment: @mclayton - the flat backed left arrow is O.k., the blank button is the mystery, the third button (with chevroned back) is just for testing.

Comment: @Theo - thanks for the link - I will have to switch symbols but was curious about the anomaly with the [char]0x84 symbol. There must be an underlying reason, and hopefully a workaround.

Comment: @Doofus - ah, got you. I can reproduce it here, fwiw. No idea what’s causing it though…

Comment: Still stumped, [char]0x84 in a RichTextBox is fine.

Comment: What's wrong on any of the following Unicode? - `⮘` (U+2B98,  *THREE-D TOP-LIGHTED LEFTWARDS EQUILATERAL ARROWHEAD*)
- `⮚` (U+2B9A,  *THREE-D TOP-LIGHTED RIGHTWARDS EQUILATERAL ARROWHEAD*)
- `⮜` (U+2B9C,  *BLACK LEFTWARDS EQUILATERAL ARROWHEAD*)
- `⮞` (U+2B9E,  *BLACK RIGHTWARDS EQUILATERAL ARROWHEAD*) - `⮘` (U+2B98,  *THREE-D TOP-LIGHTED LEFTWARDS EQUILATERAL ARROWHEAD*)
- `⮚` (U+2B9A,  *THREE-D TOP-LIGHTED RIGHTWARDS EQUILATERAL ARROWHEAD*)

Comment: or - `⮜` (U+2B9C,  *BLACK LEFTWARDS EQUILATERAL ARROWHEAD*)
- `⮞` (U+2B9E,  *BLACK RIGHTWARDS EQUILATERAL ARROWHEAD*) - `⏴` (U+23F4,  *BLACK MEDIUM LEFT-POINTING TRIANGLE*)
- `⏵` (U+23F5,  *BLACK MEDIUM RIGHT-POINTING TRIANGLE*)
- `▶` (U+25B6,  *Black Right-Pointing Triangle*)
- `▷` (U+25B7,  *White Right-Pointing Triangle*)
- `◀` (U+25C0,  *Black Left-Pointing Triangle*)
- `◁` (U+25C1,  *White Left-Pointing Triangle*)
- `⯇` (U+2BC7,  *BLACK MEDIUM LEFT-POINTING TRIANGLE CENTRED*)
- `⯈` (U+2BC8,  *BLACK MEDIUM RIGHT-POINTING TRIANGLE CENTRED*)

Comment: @JosefZ - thank you for the suggested alternatives to the [char]0x84 character. Any of them will suffice. My question was about one of those directional arrows in particular. I am resigned to switch to an alternative . However, my belief is that computers were made by people, to serve people, and to do so they must follow the instructions they are given. When, after considerable effort, they don`t do that we deserve an explanation and I believe the readers of this forum are best placed to help uncover that explanation.